# What are miscellaneous bindings? and why are they giving me a port error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am getting this error, that seems to have no negative effect on anything, but still.. why?

chrome console :

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.                                 miscellaneous_bindings:235
    chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to worry about those. They do not affect your own code. **They originate in one of your Chrome extensions.** This usually happens when an extension is trying to establish a connection to a local file (for instance when using the `file:` protocol).